# SQL language use 'Desc'

Tags: sql

I test my SQL language find one question, When I delete 'desc' the SQL running so fast but when I add 'desc', the SQL running so slowly. How could I optimize my SQL language. Thank you very much.

```
DELETE FROM [WHRW_BATCH] 
WHERE [Start_TM] NOT IN (SELECT TOP 10000 [Start_TM] 
                         FROM [WHRW_BATCH] 
                         ORDER BY [Start_TM] DESC
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Is your data index sorted asc? That might explain why ordering it desc takes time

Comment: sorry, I make tag not clearly. It's SQL SERVER, thx.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like SQL Server syntax.  In that database, I would suggest an updatable CTE:

```
WITH todelete AS (
      SELECT wb.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_TM DESC) as seqnum 
      FROM WHRW_BATCH wb
     )
DELETE FROM todelete
    WHERE seqnum > 10000;
```

This will keep the 10,000 most recent records.

If the table is quite large (i.e. most records are being deleted), then you might find a temporary table is faster:

```
select top (10000) wb.*
into temp_whrw_batch
from WHRW_BATCH wb
order by Start_TM desc;
```

Then remove all rows from the table and re-insert:

```
truncate table WHRW_BATCH;

insert into WHRW_BATCH
    select *
    from temp_whrw_batch;
```